# Iron router sublayouts - getting data context on yield

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Consider the following templates:

1. layout
2. pageLayoutStandard
3. aboutUs

'layout' is my top-level template, which I specify using:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
});
```

Inside layout.html I have the following:

```
<main id="site-main" role="main">
  {{>Template.dynamic template=page.pageLayoutTemplate }}
</main>
```

I pass some data in from the route: a page object which has a property 'pageLayoutTemplate', having the value 'pageLayoutStandard'.

Inside 'pageLayoutStandard' template, I have:

```
{{> yield }}
```

If I visit the '/about-us' route, I render the 'aboutUs' template into 'pageLayoutStandard' - no worries.

**And now to my problem...**

In my 'aboutUs' template, I expect the 'data' property of the instance to contain the data I passed down from iron-router. However, I find that my the data property contains a 'Template' object; specifically, it contains 'pageLayoutStandard'.

So it looks like 'yield' doesn't like living in a sub-layout - it wants to live at the top level layout for it to get the data from the route. This I validated by moving my yield to the top level layout - the 'aboutUs' template then gets the right data.

Is there any way I can get 'yield' to get the correct data context when it exists in a sublayout?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to access the data using

```
Router.current().data()
```

Answer (score 1):

I my self am fairly new to Iron-Router, but I believe it may be a similar issue that I cam across in another way. There are also several ambiguities in your question, such as where and how are you specifically defining the data context.

Basically I discovered that `{{> yield}}` creates it's own `<body>` tags. This also means that things like `Template.body.events();` don't propagate into this new Iron-router `<body>`. This is a known ["bug" with Iron-Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/606#issuecomment-200818724).

There is a [workaround](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-body-events) that has been developed to solve that particular issue, but I'm not sure it's relevant to your case, or at least may not solve the problem since you are not looking to propagate the main body template.

In the end it may be that your routing logic is somewhat inverted, as you mentioned, with the intended usage of Iron-Router.

I believe a better way to perform what you want would be to have:

```
<main id="site-main" role="main">
  {{> yield}}
</main>
```

With something like this in your router definition

```
Router.map(function (){
  this.route("/about-us", {
    template: "pageLayoutStandard"
  }
});
```

You should then be able to set your data context and rendering as per usual.

Comment: I have a feeling this issue may have been resolved in a version of iron router since I asked my question... but unfortunately I no longer have access to the source code of the project in question to check!

By the way, I was using cascading page layouts, with child layouts inside the first level layout (hence my use of 'Template.dynamic' inside the layout)

Comment: Ok, I understand your use of dynamic templates. Usually I only use dynamic templates when having to create template renderings that are not a part of the route (for instance a popup or modal view).